# ODBC Data Source Administrator Window Crashes

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, 64-bit, dsn

I would really appreciate some help with this. Running

1. Windows 2008 R2 EE x64 SP1 with latest updates
2. Office 2010 X64 (verified) with latest updates

When I create a System DSN with an Excel spreadsheet as the source and click on the "Select Workbook" button, the ODBC Data Source Administrator Window crashes/closes automatically. I tried to do this from the command line, using the following syntax:

odbcconf configdsn "Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)" "DriverId=790|Dbq=C:\temp\DSCOLUMNS.xls|DefaultDir=C:\temp|DSN=DSCOLUMNS|description=yada yada"

and it gives me the following error message

CONFIGDSN Unable to create a datasource for the "Microsoft Excel driver (*.xls)' driver. Component not found in the registry with the error code -2147467259.

seems like this is an architecture mismatch error. but why? I am running x64 everything. please help!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are using the right configuation extension - excel 201o .xlsx instead of .xls? or are you using an excel workbook saved in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be missing installation of components. You may try what it is suggested on these two sites:

[Error message setting up System DSN: Setup routines not found. Please reinstall drive](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sqldataaccess/thread/4054aef6-c404-4cdb-b738-a1fbb10995cc)

["Error 1919. Error configuring ODBC data source" error messages when you run the Setup program for Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818954)